# Cannot subscript a value of type NSObject

Tags: ios, swift

This code:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
var significatLocationManager : CLLocationManager?

private func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    if(UIApplication.shared.backgroundRefreshStatus == UIBackgroundRefreshStatus.available){
        print("Yes")
    }else{
        print("No")
    }

    if let launchOpt = launchOptions{
        if (launchOpt[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey] != nil) {
            self.significatLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
            self.significatLocationManager?.delegate = self
            self.significatLocationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                self.significatLocationManager!.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
            }
            self.significatLocationManager?.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

        }else{
            self.locationManager           = CLLocationManager()
            self.locationManager?.delegate = self
            self.locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                self.locationManager!.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
            }
            self.locationManager?.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        }

    }else{

        self.locationManager           = CLLocationManager()
        self.locationManager?.delegate = self
        self.locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            self.locationManager!.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        }

        self.locationManager?.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

    }

    return true
}
```

Gives this error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[NSObject : AnyObject]' with an index of type 'UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey'

I have no idea what this means. Any help?

I am compiling Swift 4.0 in Xcode 10.2.1.

Comment: Looks like you have some code from an old version of Swift. Or you have code from a new version and you’ve pasted it into an old project?

Comment: Answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issues is with function signatures and with below line

```
  if (launchOpt[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey] != nil)
```

In didFinishLaunchOptions you are using launch options as old method`[NSObject : AnyObject]?` and accessing launch options with latest method `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey`

**Old method**

```
 private func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool
```

**Latest method**

```
private func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
```

Comment: pleasure happy coding.